# Show posts by tag based on title, in custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, advanced-custom-fields

On my website I have a directory (custom post type) filled with companies, each have their own listings page. Now at the bottom of the page I want to display all posts which are tagged with the title of that company as shown in the their directory listing page.

Directory Page

**Example Company**
Related posts for **Example Company**

For testing, I manually put 'rennicks' as the tag. Then added 'rennicks' as a tag in about 5 posts, and they all displayed in the listings page fine. But obviously I need it to dynamically retrieve the title and search for tag based on the data in that variable.

```
$original_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$args=array('tag' => 'rennicks');
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( have_posts() ) :
?>
    <?php
        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns content-excerpt">
                <div class="thumbnail medium-6 columns nopm">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    <p><?php //the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <div class="related-stats-info">
                        <ul>
                            <!-- <li><?php //the_author(); ?></li> -->
                            <li><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <?php the_date('Y-m-d') ?></li>
                            <li><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> <?php comments_number( '0 comments', '1 comment', '% comments' ); ?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <div class="clearboth"></div>
<?php
endif;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $original_query;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the end goal is. Do you want to dynamically change the tag that is being brought in, instead of hard coding 'rennicks'? So, maybe you're trying to get all tags used by posts of your custom type?

Comment: Got it! Well, that won't be a problem but there is only thing we will need to sort out first. Tags (AFAIK) can not have spaces in them, and some of your titles have spaces. What would you think if we used the slug as the tag instead of the title? Alternatively, we could consider using a wordpress extension like Advanced Custom Fields or Types to get a link between multiple posts without using the tags field.

Comment: Slug would do fine too yes. I have ACF also. Slug would be best for me if possible.

Comment: Hey Jordan! Could you pick an answer for this issue?

Comment: Hey Mikel, sorry had to pop out but yep works perfect now, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to get the post slug, so first I would read that comment and verify that you're getting the slug. Try maybe doing a var_dump($slug); exit; right after the slug variable to verify you have its correct value. Once you do, try giving this a shot:

```
// Get the slug (This is assuming you 
// have the current post in a $post 
// variable. Otherwise, load the post 
// with the post ID like so:
// $post = get_post( $post_id );
$slug = $post->post_name;

// Build args array for query, replacing hyphens with nothing on the slug.
$args = array('tag' => str_replace('-', '', $slug));

// Set wp_query with tag args
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// If we get result posts from our query...
if ( have_posts() ) :?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns content-excerpt">
            <div class="thumbnail medium-6 columns nopm">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                <p><?php //the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <div class="related-stats-info">
                    <ul>
                        <!-- <li><?php //the_author(); ?></li> -->
                        <li><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <?php the_date('Y-m-d') ?></li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> <?php comments_number( '0 comments', '1 comment', '% comments' ); ?></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <div class="clearboth"></div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php 
// Reset wordpress...
wp_reset_query();
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Yep it's definitely getting the slug correct, 'rennicks-mts' for this example. Set 3 more articles to the tag 'rennicks-mts' but simply nothing returned on the listings page. Tried the tag on a different listing page also but same again. Hmm.

Comment: It's weird, if I quickly change $slug to a static tag and just one word it seems to work. rennicks works but rennicks-mts doesn't even if static.

Also, if I change it to use the post_id instead, it simply ignores the tag and brings up 10 most recent posts.

Comment: I wonder if perhaps the hyphen is causing issues when querying for that tag? Perhaps try tagging a few posts with 'rennicksmts' and hardcoding that into the slug. If that works we could try to remove hyphens from the slug and go that route...

Comment: I know you wanted to stick to using tags but I believe that this should be related with a different method. Advanced custom fields has a relationship field. I'd recommend using this, perhaps as checkboxes or a multi-select. I'd call the field "This post is related to:", allowing people to pick any number of fields that this one is related to. Some good docs on using a process like this: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/customize-the-relationship-field-list-htm/

Comment: ok! I've updated my answer to remove the hyphens from the slug. This should work for you, but let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: Hi Mikel , I thought I'd give the relationship field a try also, any chance we could PM on this? I'm trying to figure this one out. Probably shouldn't start a new question either.

Comment: I don't believe stack overflow allows PMs? I would start by using Advanced Custom Fields, making a multi-select field, and then populating the field with all potentially related posts: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/dynamically-populate-a-select-fields-choices/ http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/select/